# Codename One - Hide Animation for single Element removes everything

Tags: java, animation, codenameone

I was following a basic tutorial on how to start animating things in a mobile app created with Codename One.

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/animations.html

While I get the concept of using layout animation and unlayout animation on containers to move things into place and out of place, this does not seem to work properly for the unlayout animation.

The thought of below code is to have a list of elements that are either shown or hidden based on some search results (the example has just plain labels).
Animating things in place works well when used alone, as shown in the tutorial.

But why does everything vanish completely when calling "animateUnlayoutAndWait()"?

```
Form hi = new Form("Layout Animations", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Button button = new Button("Hide");
        hi.add(button);

        for (int iter = 0; iter < 10; iter++) {
            Label b = new Label("Label " + iter);
            b.setWidth(button.getWidth());
            b.setHeight(button.getHeight());
            b.setY(-button.getHeight());
            hi.add(b);
        }

        button.addActionListener((e) -> {

            // hide every second label on click
            if (button.getText().equals("Hide")) {
                button.setText("Show");
                for (int iter = 1; iter < hi.getContentPane().getComponentCount(); iter += 2) {
                    Component c = hi.getContentPane().getComponentAt(iter);
                    c.setHidden(false);
                }
                hi.getContentPane().animateUnlayoutAndWait(500, 0);

            }
            // show stuff again
            else {
                button.setText("Hide");
                for (int iter = 1; iter < hi.getContentPane().getComponentCount(); iter += 2) {
                    Component c = hi.getContentPane().getComponentAt(iter);
                    c.setHidden(true);
                }
                hi.getContentPane().animateLayoutAndWait(500);
            }
        });

        hi.show();
```

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Try changing it to `animateUnlayout()` and remove the `AndWait` part.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you mistakenly swapped `setHidden()` values, the `if` part should true while the `else` part should be false. Also, remove the `AndWait` from your animation.

```
Form hi = new Form("Layout Animations", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Button button = new Button("Hide");
hi.add(button);

for (int iter = 0; iter < 10; iter++) {
    Label b = new Label("Label " + iter);
    b.setWidth(button.getWidth());
    b.setHeight(button.getHeight());
    b.setY(-button.getHeight());
    hi.add(b);
}

button.addActionListener((e) -> {

    // hide every second label on click
    if (button.getText().equals("Hide")) {
        button.setText("Show");
        for (int iter = 1; iter < hi.getContentPane().getComponentCount(); iter += 2) {
            Component c = hi.getContentPane().getComponentAt(iter);
            c.setHidden(true); //should be true here
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateUnlayout(500, 255, null); //remove AndWait

    } // show stuff again
    else {
        button.setText("Hide");
        for (int iter = 1; iter < hi.getContentPane().getComponentCount(); iter += 2) {
            Component c = hi.getContentPane().getComponentAt(iter);
            c.setHidden(false); //should be false here
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(500); //remove AndWait
    }
});

hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:
- true and false is correct. haven't paid attention to it, as the result was that everything vanished in both cases anyways.
- whether I wait for it to finish or not does not matter in this case, as I call it only case and not repeatedly on several elements.
- one more thing you changed is setting the target opacity of the unlayout animation from 0 to 255. This way, all elements remain visible.

This brings me to two questions:
1. why is unlayout animation applied to all elements in my form, not only to those whose properties were changed (position values)? When using

```
animateUnlayoutAndWait(500, 0);
```

everything will vanish, even the button.

2. with the current solution from diamond, when calling unlayout animation, the individual elements that should disappear vanish instantly, the only thing element being animation is label 8, and it is animation INTO place, rather than out of place.